# Common Index Action for all controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Currently to return view, I have to write one method in all the controllers. That is "Index" action method. It has nothing to do except returning their respective views.

So is it possible to make them common?

I have inherited one common basecontroller which is inherited from apicontroller. So is there a way that I write base index method. and i can override it as well if needed?

Comment: I would go for the [KISS-principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Just copy the code. It's more obvious. You already noticed the drawback:  AmbiguousActionException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a BaseController class like this:

```
  public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public virtual IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Then inherit your controller clasess from base controller:

```
public class CustomersController : BaseController
    {

    }
```

You can override the Index method like this:

```
 public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public override IActionResult Index()
    {

        return View("About");
    }
}
```

Comment: that resulted into following error:
 AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:

MyAppNamespace.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MyAppName)
MyAppNamespace.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MyAppName)

Comment: You have to either remove Index method from your HomeController class if you are inheriting from base controller class or you have to use the override keyword with Index method

Comment: I removed from homecontroller class. still it gives me this error.

Comment: Are you using MVC areas in your application?

Comment: Oops. My bad. I removed from another controllers. Homecontroller had still that. Thats what I was missing. very silly mistake. Thanks.

Comment: The name BaseController is quite confusing: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1